# UPDATE VALUES OF COLUMN IN POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 4 tables:

```
1. matchsal 
ID salaray
1  1000
2  2000
3  3000
4  4000
5  5000

2. TABLE1
ID   C
1   NA
2   NA
3   NA
4   NA
5   NA

3. TABLE2
ID   lfs1   lfs2
1    2      3
2    3      1
3    3      1
4    3      1
5    2      3

4. TABLE3
ID_NIC    filternn
1         private
2         public
3         private
4         Private
5         public
```

what i want is to update table1 with the salary values from matchsal table
with conditions in the others tables, i tried this query:

```
update TABLE1 LFS
SET  C1= (Select SALARY from matchsal ss )
WHERE LFS."ID" IN
(   SELECT "ID" from
        TABLE2 lfs,
        TABLE3 NIC
    WHERE lfs."ID"=NIC."ID_NIC" 
    and lfs.lfs1 <> LFS.lfs2
    and filternn in ( 'Private'))
```

and i got this error:
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
SQL state: 21000

Comment: What don't you understand?  The error seems pretty clear.

Comment: I need to fix it, and i don't see the answer :"

Comment: @NoraS will the salary be 4000 for all the ID in table1?

Comment: No, there id should match with ids in matchsal  table, so it should be 1000,3000,4000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer ^^"
It is simple thing

```
update TABLE1 LFS
SET  C1= (Select SALARY from matchsal ss where ss.id=LFS."ID" limit 1)
WHERE LFS."ID" IN
(   SELECT "ID" from
        TABLE2 lfs,
        TABLE3 NIC
    WHERE lfs."ID"=NIC."ID_NIC" 
    and lfs.lfs1 <> LFS.lfs2
    and filternn in ( 'Private'))
```

I Just add a limit to the sub query

Comment: Don't you have to match ID between matchsal and table1? Otherwise it will pick any salary.

Answer (score 1):

The subquery in the `SET` is causing the problem.  It is possible that you want:

```
SET  C1 = (Select ss.SALARY from matchsal ss where ss.id = lfs.id)
```

But that is just a guess.

Comment: still face the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
update TABLE1 LFS
SET  C1= (Select ss.SALARY from matchsal ss where lfs.id=ss.id)
WHERE lfs.ID IN
(   SELECT ID from
        TABLE2 lfs,
        TABLE3 NIC
    WHERE lfs.ID=NIC.ID_NIC
    and lfs.lfs1 <> LFS.lfs2
    and filternn in ( 'Private'))
```